# Creating an invisible button in Java Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, button

I have seen many times on Java Swing GUIs buttons that look like images until the mouse rolls over them. They appear to not have their content area filled. When the mouse rolls over them, the content area fills in but the button looks as though the mouse is not hovering over it. An example of this would be the toolbar of buttons used to activate each demo in SwingSet2.

How is this effect possible?

**EDIT:** Here are images that illustrate my question:

**Default State**
[image: button_default.png]

**Hover State**
[image: button_hover.png]

**Clicked (Active) State**
[image: button_active.png]

These are using the Window Look&Feel on Vista. The images were captured from the SwingSet2 demo toolbar.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess, then, I'll have to wait until I get my wizard's license. Pity.

Comment: These two steps might work. (1) button.setOpaque(false); (2) button.setUI(new BasicButtonUI());  I got these ideas here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TabComponentsDemoProject/src/components/ButtonTabComponent.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add any JToggleButton with an icon to a JToolBar it will behave like this. If you don't want it to be in a tool bar, try `setBorderPainted(false)`. I know it works on a GTK LaF, try it with windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to do it. This code will add a resized image to the JButton and remove the button's borders and filled area except when the mouse is on the button.

```
 public JPanel hooverImages(){
        JPanel panel;
        ImageIcon icon;
        Image img;
        JButton button;
        String name = "image"


        icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gui/resources/"
                + name+".png"));
        img = icon.getImage(); 

        button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(30, 30
                , Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); //adds resized image to button.
        button.setBounds(20, 0, 40, 40);
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false); //this is the piece of code you needed
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){
                JButton buton = (JButton)event.getSource();
                buton.setContentAreaFilled(true);  //when hoovered it will show borders and fill area.
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){
                JButton buton = (JButton)event.getSource();
                buton.setContentAreaFilled(false); //when mouse is not on button then it will look the same.
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);

     return panel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I've played with any of that, but I believe it is from JButton's [setRolloverIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) inherited from AbstractButton. I believe you have to enable rollover as well.

Comment: But what icon would I pass as the argument?

Comment: I different image to display when the mouse rolls over. Run SwingSet2 and go to the button demo (second on the toolbar). Make sure you are looking at the buttons sub-tab, and then look at the source code tab. There are several examples of using different icons for different states in there: pressed, rollover, disabled, etc. Each is given a new imageIcon from a different .gif file. Download the source for it, and you should be able to open up the individual .gif files to see what they are doing to them for each one.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
This is what you want. [Flat Button](http://app.jbbres.com/developers/blog/files/a9335ea395469f9d142ce99f1459c914-0.html)

I know it says the Windows L&F, which you can set in SwingSet2, but it doesn't mean SwingSet2 didn't replace some of the underlying UI handlers to gain the effect they needed along with using the Windows L&F.

**Original Response**

Rough version with no pictures. Change border and colors to suite your needs.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    JButton button = new JButton("Hover Me");
    button.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    button.setBounds(10, 10, 60, 40);
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            JButton button = (JButton) e.getComponent();
            button.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY.brighter());
            button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            JButton button = (JButton) e.getComponent();
            button.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        }
    });
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: This is another approach, if you want to do something fancier or mor complicated than just swapping out the button image for another on a different state. You can do all sorts of theatrics once you dig into the listeners.

Comment: But how to make this effect look like the current LAF? If you look at toolbars of programs on Windows, you can see that all you see are icons, until you roll over them, at which point they look like buttons. I will add images to my question.

Comment: This "flat button" effect is almost what I want; I will look into this. I didn't know what these buttons were called, so I called them invisible buttons.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the jButton, click properties and set Opacity to false.
OR
add this to your code.   JButton.setvisible(false);